# If else statement is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a form validator that requires at least 6 characters in the input text field. It's supposed to show error if the length is less than 6 and Matched! if its more than 6. But, it's showing error no matter how long the character is.

```js
$(function() {
  let texts = $("#txt").val();
  let password = $("#pass").val();

  $("#frm").submit(function(e) {
    if (texts.length < 6) {
      $("#text-adder").text("Error");
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $("#text-adder").text("Matched!");
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Add your HTML also

Comment: `texts` will always be the initial value, move `let texts = $("#txt").val();` inside the event handler

Comment: You have to get the texts value when you submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#frm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();   
  if ($("#txt").val().length < 6) {
    $("#text-adder").text("Error");

  } else {
    $("#text-adder").text("Matched!");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the text & password value inside the submit function. This is because the on submit it needed to check the value. But if you get it outside the submit function that will not get the updated value on submit

```js
$("#frm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let texts = $("#txt").val();
  let password = $("#pass").val();
  if (texts.length < 6) {
    $("#text-adder").text("Error");

  } else {
    $("#text-adder").text("Matched!");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually get the value of the `#txt` field inside the submit function so that the value is updated with the latest value:

```
$(function() {
  $("#frm").submit(function(e) {
    let texts = $("#txt").val();
    let password = $("#pass").val();
    if(texts.length < 6) {
        $("#text-adder").text("Error");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $("#text-adder").text("Matched!");
    }
  })
});
```